# How to convert coordinates o a point from y^2=x^3+7 to y^2=x^3+4?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

**To moderator, this my question is not off topic !!! Please OPEN MY QUESTION. If for this place elliptic curves was off topic this so world  is crazy.**

`p = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663`

$E4 = EllipticCurve(GF(p), [0,4])$

$E7 = EllipticCurve(GF(p), [0,7])$

`base_x = 0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798`

`base_y = 0x483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8`

Basepoint of $y^2=x^3+7$
$BP = E7(base_x, base_y, 1)$

#Point on $y^2=x^3+7$
`Q = E([81119306557295043947776230900539651493257160932663731932698523086255548483211,69833235478127881789123626297864036834549011744885041054439092651501655231589])`

#base point of $y^2=x3+4$

`BasePoint2( [44959049921401095561708555029356671875656137150174062590365663013295388555357, 83434812528180346320431259926231725911951822121210091498845843183726829396473])`

- How to convert coordinates of $Q(x,y)$ on $y^2=x3+7$ to coordinates in $y^2=x3+4$ ? Code needed(SAGE, Python etc.).

> Q = E([81119306557295043947776230900539651493257160932663731932698523086255548483211,69833235478127881789123626297864036834549011744885041054439092651501655231589])`

#base point of $y^2=x3+4$

`BasePoint2( [44959049921401095561708555029356671875656137150174062590365663013295388555357, 83434812528180346320431259926231725911951822121210091498845843183726829396473])`

- How to convert coordinates of $Q(x,y)$ on $y^2=x3+7$ to coordinates in $y^2=x3+4$ ? Code needed(SAGE, Python etc.).

**EDITED:**

Firs of all, Big thank's to all and most to @corpsfini
I need extend my question:

Then I use same data for curves : y^2 = x^3+1, y^2 = x^3+2, y^2 = x^3+3,y^2 = x^3+6. All this curves is a sextic twist's !
Base points:

for k=1
`BP1 = G1([85121563011366687025707822879925964033143920255507899862530934382179124106759, 42409656727948788569510737393982221864295921023467166630061319157315739523945])`

for k=2 (two base points !)

BP2 = G2([34450129095809207277443089178970023159365999968937291419691966854030888759742, 103113457269188258644933175729489183329932073011449500633910298163941611786454])'

`BP22 = E2([24677754846515895310822934803022252124056730057362245386150209044791887143233, 41719207854450575864606406013013508426241430134433644860265981543689324807921])`

**for k =3 (3  base points )**

`G31 = E3([93579283295185043256820683457089915228054046133395133419577655037763911527649, 112632096923660630255684142108084503413038643268482102767008195691777477419906])`

`G32 = E3([58789712228735767534689054670947929274317202597024413724449599685590434047265, 107321344524132116458593462114893821989989072136438106411838048313086057432231])`

`G33 = E3([47858481801281315626533839795712036122864957874172974111026342690985232356030, 63537630893779210652619453277142775650521136639503000828326021732442685337139])`

**for k=6 (4 base points)**

`G61 = E6([80405269462255682739463837712137497998977949201059835857866434498654712080197, 48691579481383569995627909330664108505064081380828260061217816961756876411246])`

`G62 =  E6([12432617283785513902347690216509117019297835774706912333697948746440679211150, 83708142459295252500884287758641092902751782412362742187118587574926797876389])`

`G63 = E6([111791420809596458879302671914977681383209776367646894239671494718518178664717, 49961896499747108603390684299676279195265984395588907081892517506172789566751])`

`G64 = E6([68559020522988484359921009775181052297262355171078713712064230001578345410040, 5828734597053595677172176259754174961452737034616688535269967754301263707463])`

But then I try check cordiality a have a problem:
`p = 157920892373161954235709850086879078532699846656405640394575840079088 34671663`

`Fp6.<x> = GF(p^6, name='x', modulus=x^6 + 5*x^5 - 6*x^4 - 53*x^3 - 41*x^2`+ 44*x + 31)`

`E7 = EllipticCurve(Fp6, [0, 7])`

`E4 = EllipticCurve(Fp6, [0, 6])`

`E4.cardinality() == E7.cardinality()`

Error:

`inverse of Mod(0, 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663) does not exist`

help me please solve this error.

And addition questions:

**1)** can I use my basepoints with points withfinded coordinates  ?

**2)**

```
K.<z> = Fp6[]
f = z^6*7 - 4
mu = f.roots(multiplicities=False)[0]
```

**Can I replace a "4" to "1" in this calculus for find *mu* for k=1 and get after good result for compute coordinates ?**

**VERY VERY BIIIIIIIIIIIG THANK'S YOU !!!**

Comment: y^2=x3+4 is a twist of y^2=x3+7

Comment: I know twist's. Looking for coordinates converter code.

Comment: For sage math code you can ask for https://ask.sagemath.org/

Comment: @Marex: Welcome to Crypto-SE. Our site's topic is cryptography, not how to use tools for cryptographic tasks. Please fix thee issues (based on [rev5](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/83542/5)) if you want the question reopened: A) it is asked _"How to convert coordinates"_ from one curve to another using the same field $\Bbb F_p$. But _the required properties of the conversion_ are not stated, and not trivial. B) The question starts straight off-topic by giving a particular prime $p$ and expressions specific to a certain tool. C) There is $x3$ where I guess it is meant $x^3$.

Comment: Moderator is afraid of actual math

Comment: As it currently stands I can of course not reopen. Please edit the question in such a way that the actual questions stand out and that anything that hasn't directly to do with the question(s) is edited out. Please remove all bold / SHOUTING at the start and end.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, the two curves are not isomorphic over the prime field $\mathbf{F}_p$ so it is not possible to map points from one curve to the other on this field. However, those curves are isomorphic over the extension field $\mathbf{F}_{p^6}$.

First part is to define the extension field using an irreducible polynomial of degree $6$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$, the we can create the curves and check that they have the same cardinality:

```
p = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
Fp6.<x> = GF(p^6, name='x', modulus=x^6 + 5*x^5 - 6*x^4 - 53*x^3 - 41*x^2 + 44*x + 31)
E7 = EllipticCurve(Fp6, [0, 7])
E4 = EllipticCurve(Fp6, [0, 4])
E4.cardinality() == E7.cardinality()
```

Since those curves are isomorphic, there exists an element $\mu \in \mathbf{F}_{p^6}$ such that the map
$$
\begin{array}{rrcl}
\varphi: & E_7 & \longrightarrow & E_4 \\
& (x,y) & \longmapsto & (\mu^2 x, \mu^3 y)
\end{array}
$$
is an isomorphism. The point $(\mu^2 x, \mu^3 y)$ of $E_4$ satisfy the equation
$$
(\mu^3 y)^2 = (\mu^2 x)^3 + 4 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad y^2 = x^3 + 4/\mu^6,
$$
so $\mu$ is a root of the polynomial $7z^6 - 4$ over the field $\mathbf{F}_{p^6}$.

```
K.<z> = Fp6[]
f = z^6*7 - 4
mu = f.roots(multiplicities=False)[0]
```

Finally, we can map the point $Q_7=(x,y)$ from $E_7$ to $E_4$:

```
Q7 = E7(81119306557295043947776230900539651493257160932663731932698523086255548483211,
        69833235478127881789123626297864036834549011744885041054439092651501655231589)
Q4 = E4(mu^2*Q7[0], mu^3*Q7[1])
```

We can add a check on the point order, since it should be the same as $Q_7$:

```
q = 2^256 - 432420386565659656852420866394968145599 
q*Q7
q*Q4
```

The value $q$ is the order of $Q_7$ and in both cases, we are supposed to get the infinity point.

Comment: Just wondering, is there a theory about the isomorphism on the extension field? How one does know that they are isomorphic in $\mathbf{F}_{p^6}$?

Comment: It has to do with the fact that this curve has a sextic twist, so a curve and its twist are isogeneous over an extension field of degree $6$ (and for quadratic twists, over an extension field of degree $2$).

Comment: So the tow curves are the sextic twist of each other. Does the fact have some theorems or just intuition? Or, try 2,3,...

Comment: These two curves have the same $j$-invariant so they are isomorphic over the algebraic closure of the field, but in particular the $j$-invariant is $0$ so it happens that in this case the smallest field on which they are isomorphic is $\mathbf{F}_{p^6}$.

Answer (score 1):

The curves have different orders, you can not map points from one to another in a useful way. Second, the curves are not twists of each other, since their orders do not add up to p + 2.